# .htaccess from specific UNIX group

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix, authentication

I need to create a login for users from the group `users`. Now I have this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile path??
```

What is the path to the .htaccess for users from the group `users`? How can I solve this?

Comment: replaced the `server` tag by `apache`, since this is clearly what you are referring to. Also, this may be better suitable for ServerFault ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a system group (you wrote "UNIX group"): use mod_authz_unixgroup and mod_authnz_external.

```
AddExternalAuth pwauth  /usr/sbin/pwauth
SetExternalAuthMethod   pwauth  pipe
...
<Location /path/to/restricted/...>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted area"
  AuthBasicProvider external
  AuthExternal pwauth
  AuthzUnixgroup on
  Require group ...
</Location>
```

Comment: @Kevin: oh. Glad to be of help. Thought already I got mislead because you had accepted the other answer :)